# State of the pylab import?

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

There is a proposal to unify, simplify and build consistency within the scipy, numpy and matplotlib namespaces so that:

```
from pylab import *
```

is equivilent to:

```
from scipy import *
from numpy import *
from pylab import * (although I personally think it should be from matplotlib)
```

It's been over 3 years since http://www.scipy.org/PyLab was first written (refer to mailling list discussion linked from that proposal http://matplotlib.1069221.n5.nabble.com/Pylab-import-error-due-to-dateutil-td39346.html)

Is there an update on progress on this or has it stalled? This question is really calling out to someone who has been following the dev mailling lists of the relevant packages numpy, scipy, matplotlib, ipython etc

[EDIT]

There is more to this than just polluting the toplevel namespace. It is about unifying the API of the four aforementioned packages and streamlining the process for scientific programming. Personally in my work, I find that if I need numpy, I always need matplotlib and I often require something from scipy.

Comment: `from pylab import *` already does a `from numpy import *` and a `from pyplot import *` behind the scenes. It's only `scipy` that's missing.

Comment: To add (without having read the proposal or discussion), this is obviously to make it more matlab/maple/IDL/<favourite data analysis tool> like. It does pollute the namespace, but for scientists (not specifically programmers), it does provide an incredible convenience in analysing data. I personally would even add `from sympy import *` to give it a bit of Mathematica flavour as well :-).

Comment: Just FYI, there's no point in adding `from scipy import *` there. That doesn't actually import anything from `scipy`. It just imports everything in the `numpy` namespace (plus one or two functions and makes a few of the numpy functions have different defaults for historical reasons).  `maplotlib`'s `pylab` is already what you're describing.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like it has been discussed since 2009 (although the wiki page was updated a couple of months ago). 
I agree with the sentiment of one of the posts in the mpl mailing list:

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
...
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

I can see the benefit of having a consistent documentation strategy between the projects, but having one monolithic namespace I am less than convinced on...

In terms of implementation, the matplotlib `pylab` namespace is still around on master today (and therefore will be part of the upcoming 1.2 release), so there is certainly no short term plan for this to be taken forward. I would consider getting in touch with the author of the page you are referring to to see what their plans are.

HTH

Comment: I sincerely agree with the namespaces sentiment too. I personally wouldn't import all into the main name space, but i find it superflous to import all three np, sp, and mpl everytime I start a script. I already import os, csv, datetime, logging, and others as a matter of course and this proposal could simplify things a little.

Comment: I also prefer to use the namespaces too, because "Explicit is better than implicit", although sometimes the first part of the script can be a list of 10 or more imports.